# ¿Cómo se puede acceder normalmente Sql Server, después de estos errores?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-management

Estaba realizando un respaldo Full de la base de datos, el respaldo se llama CentroMedico1.

El problema es que una vez que se realizó, cerré SQL Server Management y cuando intente entrar con sesión SQL server apareció el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comencé a indagar la manera de entrar e intente entrar con autenticación de windows, y al ver las bases de datos de lado izquierdo, me apareció lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La base original que se respaldo es CentroMedico, la otra es la respaldada.
*se quedo ciclada ahí en restaurando*

Otra cosa que investigue e intente para restaurar la sesión de SQL y la base de datos original fue: restaurar el Log de la base de datos original;

```
RESTORE LOG [CentroMedico]
FROM DISK = N'C:\Backup_SQL\CentroMedico.bak'
```

Y tengo los siguientes errores:

```
Msg 4326, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The log in this backup set terminates at LSN 37000000351200001, which is too early to apply to the database. A more recent log backup that includes LSN 37000000356800001 can be restored.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE LOG is terminating abnormally.
```

¿Qué se puede hacer para restaurar la base de datos original y poder iniciar sesión con autenticación sql server?

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si has logrado ingresar con la autenticación de windows quizá
puedas cambiar la contraseña o asignarle roles al usuario sa

Comment: Cambiando contraseña marca el mismo error, y no me permite agregarle más roles: marca error.